# Efficiency of constrained LQR formulation in CVXPY via batch-approach

Tags: optimal-control, quadratic-programming, cvxpy

I am interested in formulating a discrete finite time constrained LQR in CVXPY.

\begin{align}
\text{minimize } J = & \sum_{k=0}^N x'(k)Qx(k) + u'(k)Ru(k) \\\\
\text{subject to } & x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) \\\\
& Cx(k) + Du(k) \leq e
\end{align}

I came across the *batch-approach* [1] in a paper solving a similar problem [2]. As I understand it, the method is describing the problem only in terms of the inputs $u$ and initial state $x_0$, which would reduce the total amount of variables in CVXPY in exchange for computing some large matrices beforehand.

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(0) \\\\ x_1 \\\\ \dots \\\\ \dots \\\\ x_k
\end{bmatrix} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\\\ A \\\\ \dots \\\\ \dots \\\\ A^N
\end{bmatrix} x(0) +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \\\\
B & 0 & \dots & 0 \\\\
AB & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
A^{N-1}B & \dots & \dots & B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_0 \\\\ \vdots \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{N-1}
\end{bmatrix} \\\\
X &= S^x x(0) + S^uU_0 \\\\
\end{align}

So the cost function can be rewritten to be dependent only on $x_0$ and $u$

$$
J(x(0), U_0) = X'\bar{Q}X + U_0'\bar{R}U_0
$$

The linear constraints on $x(k)$ can be rewritten similarly.

Would this be a more efficient way to define my problem in CVXPY, assuming I would be creating these large matrices in numpy? Is this something that's done in practice?

This transformation isn't applied or anywhere mentioned in [CVXPY's example on control](https://colab.research.google.com/github/cvxgrp/cvx_short_course/blob/master/book/docs/intro/notebooks/control.ipynb)

---

[1]: Borrelli, F., A. Bemporad . M. Morari: Predictive control for linear
and hybrid systems. Cambridge University Press, 2017.
[2] Gutjahr B, Gröll L, Werling M. Lateral vehicle trajectory optimization using constrained linear time-varying MPC. IEEE Transactions on Intelligent Transportation Systems. 2016 Oct 19;18(6):1586-95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mathematics point of view the reformulated problem is the same. Only the different formulation fits the more general [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problem framework. Therefore, it might be that a more efficient solvers has been developed for it.

The given structure of the optimization problem cast as a quadratic programming problem might benefit from using sparse matrices. But the best way to know which implementation is more efficient/faster for any particular problem, is by implementing both and test which one is better.

Also note that the problem that you are solving, LQR+inequality constraints, is also a form of [model predictive control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_predictive_control), for which quadratic programming solvers are used [1].

[1]: Schwenzer, M., Ay, M., Bergs, T., & Abel, D. (2021). Review on model predictive control: An engineering perspective. The International Journal of Advanced Manufacturing Technology, 117(5), 1327-1349.

Comment: I am indeed using a quadratic programming solver ([OSQP](https://osqp.org/docs/solver/index.html#problem-statement)), CVXPY is able to reformulate the problem for me. It isn't, however, dropping the x variables as in the question, so I was wondering whether it's worth doing this myself manually.

Comment: @BoyanHristov I have zero experience with CVXPY, so I can't help you with this.

Comment: I guess you're right that the only way to know for sure is to implement both methods.